# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException - No bean named blPU is defined - Cannot inject EntityManager JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a class which looks something like this..

```
@Repository("myService")
@Transactional
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao
{
@PersistenceContext(unitName="blPU")
protected EntityManager em;

@Resource(name="blEntityConfiguration")
protected EntityConfiguration entityConfiguration;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Person findPersonByUsername(String username)
    {       
        System.out.println("The entity manager is "+em);
                // ....
    }

}
```

and the `persistence.xml` which is located in `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

```
<persistence-unit name="blPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/web</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.mycompany.dao.MyDaoImpl</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="/sql/import_storage.sql"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

But I am getting the following error..

```
[artifact:mvn] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'blPU' is defined
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
```

The jta data source is declared as follows..

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/web"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              testWhileIdle="true"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              testOnReturn="false"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1"
              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
              maxActive="15"
              maxIdle="10"
              minIdle="5"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
              removeAbandoned="false"
              logAbandoned="true"
              minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
              jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
              username="${database.user}"
              password="${database.password}"
              driverClassName="${database.driver}"
              url="${database.url}"/>
```

Comment: Could you post your spring configuration and especially the part where the entity manager factory is created?

Comment: The entity manager factory is container managed. It uses JNDI

Comment: The datasource is container managed not the entity manager factory. Do you not have a bean of type `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` in your Spring configuration? If not, that is the problem

Comment: Thank you. No, there is no such bean in the spring configuration. But for some of the pre defined classes of my framework, the entity manager is injected. Those classes are actually jars placed in the lib folder. How is it injected for them and not for my custom classes?

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the `applicationContext.xml` solved the problem.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Thanks for the helpful comments of @geoand